# how to separate library and code

Tags: maven, spring-boot

My spring boot application jar is very big size, it is about 58 MB, how to separate library and modified code ? For testing purpose, I send this jar via email to my client, it is very hard for me. Any solution for my problem ?

please guide me

this is my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.sahmada.spring</groupId>
    <artifactId>myclient</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>myclient</name>
    <description>myclient app</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <start-class>com.sahmada.spring.TirayApplication</start-class>
        <!-- <java.version>1.7</java.version> -->
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- org.springframework.ui.jasperreports.jasperreportsutils maven -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-support</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.8</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
            <version>5.6.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sourceforge.barbecue</groupId>
            <artifactId>barbecue</artifactId>
            <version>1.5-beta1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>

    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Have you tried [maven-shade-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/includes-excludes.html) which can help you to include/exclude dependencies ?

Answer (score 0):

If you exclude libraries here, your client has somehow to add them again.
What about using dropbox, amazon S3 ...